# Application REST Client on Karaf

Tags: karaf

I'am writing a simple . application deploying on Karaf 4.1.0. It's role is sending a rest request to REST API.  When I start my bundle I have an error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No message body writer has been found for class package.QueueSharedDTO, ContentType: application/json
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doResponse(WebClient.java:1149)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1094)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:894)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:428)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.method(WebClient.java:1631)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.method(WebClient.java:1626)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.post(WebClient.java:1566)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.InvocationBuilderImpl.post(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:145)
    at package.worker.service.implementation.ConnectionServiceImpl.postCheckRequest(ConnectionServiceImpl.java:114)
    at package.worker.service.implementation.ConnectionServiceImpl.sendCheck(ConnectionServiceImpl.java:103)
    at package.worker.module.QueueSharedListener.run(QueueSharedListener.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No message body writer has been found for class package.QueueSharedDTO, ContentType: application/json
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$BodyWriter.doWriteBody(WebClient.java:1222)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient$AbstractBodyWriter.handleMessage(AbstractClient.java:1091)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.doRunInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:649)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1093)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: No message body writer has been found for class com.emot.dto.QueueSharedDTO, ContentType: application/json
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.reportMessageHandlerProblem(AbstractClient.java:780)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.writeBody(AbstractClient.java:494)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$BodyWriter.doWriteBody(WebClient.java:1217)
    ... 15 more
```

Initialization  WebTarget:

```
private ConnectionServiceImpl() {
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    client.property(
            ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT,
            snifferProperties.getProperty(SnifferProperties.PARAM_REST_API_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT));
    client.property(
            ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT,
            snifferProperties.getProperty(SnifferProperties.PARAM_REST_API_READ_TIMEOUT));
    System.out.println(2);
    webTarget = client.target(buildUrl());
}
```

Send requests :

```
private synchronized boolean postCheckRequest(String path, Object content) {
    boolean result = true;
    try {
        Response response = webTarget
                .path("check")
                .path("add/one")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.json(content));
        result = (response.getStatus() == 200);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error but working");
        e.printStackTrace();
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have always the problems with Karaf... i dont understand why it . couldn't working correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is mostly not a Karaf issue, but a typical issue you may face while working with some JAX-RS implementation in non-JavaEE environment.

Exception literally says that your implementation misses message body writer. Message body writer is the class which implements class `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter`  and is responsible for serializing your data objects to some format (like JSON). There is another class named `javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader`, which does the opposite thing. All these classes are registered to JAX-RS framework as providers, extending its capabilities. Details are here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html

So, generally you must decide what you use for serializing/deserializing between your data objects and HTTP MediaType and register a proper JAX-RS provider.

With Jackson, for example, your problem can be easily solved by using one of its standard implementation: either `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`, if you use JAXB annotations, or `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider`, if you prefer Jackson annotations. Add this class in providers section of your Blueprint descriptor:

```
<jaxrs:server id="restServer" address="/rest">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            ....
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
            ....
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider"/>
            ....
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```